# Change CSS Definition with jQuery when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the image below you can see there are 2 tabs:

- All Task Activity tab
- Comments tab

When the **All Task Activity** tab is clicked on, I need to change the CSS definition for the CSS class ".Activity-comment" to "display: block;"

When the **Comments** tab is clicked on, I need to change the CSS definition for the CSS class ".Activity-non-comment" to "display: none;"

So the goal is simple, both tabs will actually be showing the HTML DOM nodes for the same Div/Data.  I will simply be showing/hiding records based on the clicked on tab.

[image]

Simple jQuery click event...

```
$('#task-modal-activity-comment-btn').click(function(e) {

    //  make CSS defintion for CSS class `.Activity-non-comment` 
    // = display: none;

    e.preventDefault();
});


$('#task-modal-activity-btn').click(function(e) {

    //  make CSS definition for CSS class `.Activity-non-comment` 
    // = display: block;

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

**Based on my 2 jQuery click events above, how could I change the CSS definition for the mentioned CSS classes?**

Comment: Are you sure you want to change definition? Usually such tasks resolve with adding/removing additional class wich change behavior

Comment: You can add a `<style>` element to the `<head>` that overrides the previously defined styles for the class. But in many cases it's easier to actually add a new class for affected elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to change definition? Usually such tasks resolve with adding/removing additional class wich change behavior

```
$('#task-modal-activity-comment-btn').click(function(e) {

    //  make CSS defintion for CSS class `.Activity-non-comment` 
    // = display: none;

    $('.Activity-comment').removeClass('hidden');
    e.preventDefault();
});


$('#task-modal-activity-btn').click(function(e) {

    //  make CSS definition for CSS class `.Activity-non-comment` 
    // = display: block;
    $('.Activity-comment').addClass('hidden');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

where 'hidden' is

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Comment: You're right I read that right after making the post, thanks for posting it though so I dont have to delete

Answer (score 2):

You could try this.

```
$('#task-modal-activity-comment-btn').click(function(e) {

//  make CSS defintion for CSS class `.Activity-non-comment` 
// = display: none;
$('.Activity-non-comment').css('display','none');
e.preventDefault();
});


$('#task-modal-activity-btn').click(function(e) {

//  make CSS definition for CSS class `.Activity-non-comment` 
// = display: block;
$('.Activity-non-comment').css('display','block');
e.preventDefault();
});
```

> give the class that you need to display by default a display block at the time of dom ready.
>   Refer the given link for more info on jquery css selectors
>   [Jquery CSS selectors](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

```
$('#task-modal-activity-comment-btn').click(function(e) {

    //  make CSS defintion for CSS class `.Activity-non-comment` 
    // = display: none;
$('.Activity-non-comment').css('display','none');

    e.preventDefault();
});


$('#task-modal-activity-btn').click(function(e) {

    //  make CSS definition for CSS class `.Activity-non-comment` 
    // = display: block;
$('.Activity-non-comment').css('display','block');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: you can use .style or .css() Also you should write into "style" attribute not into "display"